# Add a product custom input text as order item data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I would like to achieve this without buying a plugin.

Unfortunately I cannot go past the checkout phase.

Here my steps:

*// 1 Creation of the attribute*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'create_custom_attribute' );

function create_custom_attribute() {
  $args = array(
    'id'            => 'attribute-embroided-text',
    'label'         => __( 'Embroided Text', 'woocommerce' ),
    'class'                 => 'myclass',
    'value'                 => 'placeholder',
    'desc_tip'      => true,
    'custom_attributes' => array('readonly' => 'readonly'),
  );
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
```

*// 2 Saving the attribute*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_attribute' );

function cfwc_save_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $embroided_text = isset( $_POST['attribute-embroided-text'] ) ? $_POST['attribute-embroided-text'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'attribute-embroided-text', sanitize_text_field( $embroided_text ) );
}
```

*// 3 Display the attribute in the frontend*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'display_custom_attribute' );

function display_custom_attribute() {
    global $post;
    ...
    printf('<div class="">
              <h4 class="" for="attribute-embroided-text">Embroided Text/i</h4>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="attribute-embroided-text" name="attribute-embroided-text" value="">
            </div>');
    ...
}
```

*// 4 Validate the attribute*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_custom_attribute', 10, 4 );

function validate_custom_attribute( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if(empty( $_POST['attribute-embroided-text'] ) ) {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Field cannot be empty', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

*// 5 Add the attribute to cart*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_attribute_to_cart', 10, 4 );

function add_custom_attribute_to_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {
    if( ! empty( $_POST['attribute-embroided-text'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['attribute_embroided_text'] = $_POST['attribute-embroided-text'];
    } 
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

*// 6 Display the attribute in the cart*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'display_custom_attribute_into_cart', 10, 3 );

function display_custom_attribute_into_cart( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset( $cart_item['attribute_embroided_text'] ) ) {
        $name .= sprintf('<dl class="variation"><dt>Embroided Text/i:</dt><dd>%s</dd></dl>', esc_html( 
    $cart_item['attribute_embroided_text'] ));
    }
    return $name;
}
```

So the customer is able to see the field in the product page, fill it and add the product to cart and see his own custom text in the cart page.
All good until now.

But then, on the check out, I lost the information about embroided text and I am not able to pass it on.
I cannot see it in the check-out recap page
And on the back end, I don't have it in the new "order" I just received.

**My questions:**

- Is there an "order" object similar to $cart_item ?
- How can I access it? Like an usual array? *(e.g $cart_item['attribute_embroided_text'])*
- Which are the hooks that are acessing the order? (front-end and **back-end**)
- Am I doing this all wrong? Should use variations instead? *(I tried but I came at the same issue at 
  the check out)*

The whole issue can be summarized in "**how to add extra data to the order**" but I didn't find many examples or documentation about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part is the following, that will save your custom cart item data **as order item data** and will display it **everywhere** on orders and emails *(even in admin)*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_order_item_metadata', 10, 4 );
function save_custom_order_item_metadata( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset( $cart_item['attribute_embroided_text'] ) ) 
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'Embroided Text', 'woocommerce' ), $cart_item['attribute_embroided_text'] );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.